# Prolog Using lists with between inside predicate

Tags: list, prolog

I have an assignment in Prolog and I'm very not used to code in this language  :)

So I need to implement something quite simple to say but hard to me to code.

Let's say I have a square room (`Dimension` 4x4 for example).
And I want a function that has as argument `pos(Ligne,Column)` that can verify if the position entered is correct considering the square `Dimension`.

So I want it to check if `pos(1,2)` for example is true in this context.

I thought about creating a list with `findall` or `between` of valid positions considering the `Dimension` of the square and then verify if the position entered is inside this list.

But I'm quite confused.

So I have

```erlang
positif_position( pos(Ligne, Column)) :-
    Ligne >= 0, Column >= 0.

square(Dimension).
shape(square,Dimension) :- square(Dimension).

% Verifying if the position is correct here.
in_shape(pos(Ligne,Column), shape(square,Dimension)) :-
     positif_position(pos(Ligne, Column)),
     Ligne =< Dimension, Column =< Dimension,
     between(0,Dimension,Range),
     member(Ligne, [Range]), member(Column, [Range]).
```

I really don't know if the way i structured this is correct.
`in_shape(pos(1,2), shape(square,4)).` fails here and i'm not sure why.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Double posted at [SWI-Prolog discourse](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/assignment-question-about-lists-using-findall-and-between/1552?u=ericgt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```erlang
     between(0,Dimension,Range),
     member(Ligne, [Range]), member(Column, [Range]).
```

you meant

```erlang
     findall( I, between(0,Dimension,I), Range),
     member(Ligne, Range), member(Column, Range).
```

but this is superfluous. You have already checked the validity by then. Just remove those two lines. You might even have an off-by-one error there.

Comment: Ohh, i get why it is superfluous, i'm verifying the range 2 times, thankyou.

Comment: But, do you know why my example with between didn't work? i'm not sure to understand why the list `Range` didn't pass correctly in `member(Ligne, [Range]), member(Column, [Range]).`

Comment: because `[Range]` is a list with one element in it, `Range`. and the line above it, `between(0,Dimension,Range)`, sets `Range` to an integer - one integer. and another, on backtracking, and another; until it fails. but at each time the next line works, `[Range]` is a list of one integer.

Comment: so `member(Ligne, [Range])` is the same as `Ligne = Range`.

Comment: Okay i understand it, Range in my example wasn't a liste.